# Logic issue in series class

Tags: java, math, logic

I have written a class to take inputs `i , n` and then print a series: `i; ii; iii; iiii;...n` terms. So if a user inputs `5` for `3` terms, the output is `5; 55; 555;`.

```
import java.io.*;

public class replicate
{
    public void method() throws IOException
    {
        int i = 0;
        int n = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int num;
        BufferedReader obj=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        num = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter number of terms");
        n = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());

        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            x = num + (num*10);
            System.out.println (x);
        }
    }
}
```

However, running the program with input 5 for 4 terms gives the output

```
55
55
55
```

I've traced the issue to that last `for` loop. Where has my logic gone wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use a debugger.. It's your best friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `num` does not change in the loop, the expression `num + (num*10)` produces the same value in all iterations. You should use the previous value of `x` instead of `num`, like this:

```
x = x * 10 + num;
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/8KOFEF)

Comment: I love your answer because of that demo provided, and the solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
x = num + (x * 10);
```

instead of

```
x = num + (num*10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public class replicate
{
    public void method() throws IOException
    {
        int i = 0;
        int n = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int num;
        int temp;
        BufferedReader obj=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        num = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
        temp = num;
        System.out.println("Enter number of terms");
        n = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());

        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            num = temp + (num*10);
            System.out.println (num);
        }
    }
}
```

that's all